# Symfony3 Doctrine Relation Many To One

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

I have an Entity named Color and an other one named Text.
I would like for a User to be able to choose the color of the Text.
For that he will choose from pre saved color in the database.

I have managed to make it work.
So the User can pick the color, add the text.

But once the User try to add an other text and then select the same Color for the current text I get the following error :

> "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO
>   post_bloc_texte_image (texte_id, couleur_fond_id, titre_id, image_id)
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [25, 1, 18, 2]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicata du
>   champ '2' pour la clef 'UNIQ_C37A2EE3DA5256D'"

One Text should have only One selected color but an other text can select the same Color.
That's why I choose to Go with a ManyToOne Relation inside the Text Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MH\MailBundle\Entity\Tool\Couleur", cascade=   {"persist"})
 */
private $couleurFond;
```

Should I Go with a ManyToMany ? 
But I've tried to make a form with a EntityType and I could'nt make it.

```
->add('couleurFond', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'        => 'MHMailBundle:Tool\Couleur',
            'choice_label' => 'nom',
            'multiple'     => false,
        ))
```

AnyOne Got the right ways to do it ?

Thank You a lot and sorry about my english ;)

Comment: Looks like mysql is complaining about `image_id` column which has unique index at `post_bloc_texte_image` table. This exception is not related to text or color as for me. You can try drop this index if it is not needed `DROP INDEX UNIQ_C37A2EE3DA5256D ON post_bloc_texte_image`

Comment: According to you error, the "2" is your image_id. So you have a problem with the unicity of your image_id. Your manyToOne works well.